# Multi level dropdown in Angular 8 with ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm writing a code for multi level dropdown and the problem is the output looks something like the above image.

My code is :

HTML

```html
<div *ngIf="options?.length >= 1" class="dropdown-menu">   
    <a *ngFor="let option of options"
        class="dropdown-item d-flex" 
        (click)="selectOption(option)" 
        [ngStyle]="option.style">
        {{ option.name || option.node_name || option?.product_name || option?.operatorName || option?.batch_number }}
        <div *ngIf="option.sfgProducts.length >= 1" class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a *ngFor="let suboption of option.sfgProducts" 
            class="dropdown-item d-flex">
                {{ suboption.name }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```scss
.dropdown-menu{
  background: $onAccent;
  color: $accent;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left:-25px;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    background: $onAccent;
    color: $accent;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 8px;
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:hover > .dropdown-submenu {
    display: block;
  
}
.dropdown-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: $accent;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

See image below:

[image]

I dont want the dropdown-submenu to be inside first dropdown a, It should be outside the main dropdown.
How to fix this?

Comment: I can't view your screenshot link

Comment: Hello @dom.macs can u view it now?

Comment: I still can't access it

Comment: @dom.macs I have added an image directly now. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

use `positions: relative` in parent element and `position: absolute` in child element.

```css
   

    .dropdown-item {
          position: relative;
          cursor: pointer;
          min-height: 2rem;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          color: $accent;
          border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .dropdown-submenu {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          background: $onAccent;
          color: $accent;
          padding: 0.5rem;
          border-radius: 8px;
          max-height: 50vh;
          overflow-y: auto;
          display: none;
          margin-left: 25px;
        }
```

Make adjustments in `right` and `top` properties to change alignment of `.dropdown-submenu`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `.dropdown-submenu` css class, you need to add `position: absolute;`. I also added some other css like `width: 100%` to make it stretch and `margin-top: 50px` to make your sub menu go down a bit and not be aligned with your main menu but you can just remove those if you don't need it.

See code below:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
   background: $onAccent;
   color: $accent;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   border-radius: 8px;
   max-height: 50vh;
   overflow-y: auto;
   display: none;
   margin-left: 25px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I added a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xc5haz?file=src/app/app.component.css) with the solution above so that you can play around with it.